Radial space with countable pseudocharacter that isn't Fréchet Urysohn
Definitions:
Let $X$ be a topological space.
$X$ is radial if for each $A\subseteq X$ and each $p\in \overline A$ there is a transfinite sequence of points of $A$ converging to $p$.
$X$ is Fréchet Urysohn if for each $A\subseteq X$ and each $p\in \overline A$ there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $p$.
Let $X$ be $T_1$. $X$ has countable pseudocharacter if each point is a countable intersection of open sets.

I haven't found examples of $T_1$ radial spaces that have countable pseudocharacter but that aren't Fréchet-Urysohn (*). However, thinking about the hypotheses combined, I am unsure that they are strong enough to guarantee that the space is Fréchet-Urysohn. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Note that each singleton being a countable intersection of open sets implies $T_1$; no need for an additional $T_1$ assumption on the space.

Yes, indeed. It was just because the pseudocharacter is defined for $T_1$ spaces.


If $X$ is $T_1$, radial and of countable pseudocharacter, then it is Fréchet-Urysohn.

Let $A \subset X$, $p \in \overline{A}$, w.l.o.g., $ p \notin A$. 
Choose open $(U_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that
$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n = \{p\}$ and
$(x_\alpha)_{\alpha < \lambda}$ in $A$, $\lambda$ limit ordinal, such that $(x_\alpha)_\alpha$ converges to $p$.

If $\text{cof} (\lambda) = \omega$, we are done.
Thus, assume, $\text{cof} (\lambda) > \omega$.
For each $n \in \mathbb N$ there is an $\alpha_n < \lambda$ such that
$x_\alpha \in U_n$ for each $\alpha_n \le \alpha < \lambda$.

By the assumption about cofinality, there exists an upper bound $\alpha < \lambda$ of $\{\alpha_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$.
It follows
$x_\alpha \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n = \{p\}$,
contradicting $p \notin A$.

Brilliant as always. Thank you so much, Ulli.

I had to check what is the cofinality defined as.
